# Matching string that contain Metacharacters with re.findall() and re.escape()?

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

What is the regular expression for matching a sentence that contains metacharacters ?

Following the senario :

I have a string : `line = "He finally answer (after taking time to think (5 minutes) * sighs ; end)"`

I want to match this part of the sentence : `line2 = "after taking time to think (5 minutes) * sighs ; end"`

But i don't want to use a regex to find the element inside of parentheses

For that I am using : `re.findall(re.escape(line2), re.escape(line))`

But I'm getting an empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to execute the escape method over text(variable *line* in this case) you are providing:

```
import re

line = "He finally answer (after taking time to think (5 minutes) * sighs ; end)"

line2 = "after taking time to think (5 minutes) * sighs ; end" 

result = re.findall(re.escape(line2), line)

print(result) # ['after taking time to think (5 minutes) * sighs ; end']
```